# Mac pro 5.1 with Ubuntu, zotec gt 1060 Slow on Gpu Compute

Tags: gpu

I installed my Mac Pro 2010 with a Zotec GT1060 and use Ubuntu 22.

I noticed that is rendering in Cycles much faster only with CPU than with GPU Compute.

Anybody knows why?
I already installed the nvidia driver and selectet the xeon and nvidia gpu in system settings.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the card in different ways, with the sample Splash - Robot.

The card runs out of memory!

How is that possible? Are 3GB not enough for a half robot?

Is it possible to share the RAM memory to expand the VRam?